# Zoom animation not working in Android 5 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an `Activity` that has a handler. The handler does some work then launches an intent to another Activity. I use `overridePendingTransition` after I launch the intent and call `finish()`.

In Android 4.2 the zoom animation works fine but in android 5 it doesn't.

Are there any differences between the two versions of Android I need to know about with regards to animations?

```
public void initHandler(){

      handler = new Handler();
      runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                processTag();

            }

            private void processTag() {
                Log.e(TAG, "about to process tag");

                .....
                process some info
                .......


                                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run() {

                                        setContentView(R.layout.successfulnfc);

                                      }
                                    });


                            Intent processPayloadIntent = new Intent(NfcActivity.this, NfcscannerActivity.class);
                            processPayloadIntent.putExtra("payload", payload);
                            processPayloadIntent.putExtra("tagid", tagId);
                            processPayloadIntent.setAction("NFC"); 
                            processPayloadIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            //processPayloadIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivity(processPayloadIntent);
                            finish();
                            overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.activity_animation_zoom_in);





            }
        };

    }
```

..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fillAfter="false"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:startOffset="0"
        android:toXScale="0.55"
        android:toYScale="0.55" />

</set>
```

Comment: turtleboy- Did you found any solution for that? I am also facing the same issue. It works in all devices below 5.0 OS but did not work in 5.0 and above OS. Please help me if you found the solution.

Comment: @Smeet sorry i never found a solution...